# In React object updates but does not pass updated object to next function

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using React and have the following object:

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState(
    [
      {id: 1, correct: false},
      {id: 2, correct: false},
      {id: 3, correct: false},
      {id: 4, correct: false},
      {id: 5, correct: false}
    ]);
```

To update the object I have the following:

```
const onCorrectAnswerHandler = (id, correct) => {
    setRecords(
      records.map((record) => {
        if (record.id === id) {
          return { id: id, correct: true };
        } else {
          return record;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Here's the problem:

I want to run another function called `isComplete` after it but within the Handler function, that uses the changed `records` object, but it appears to use the original unchanged 'records' object (which console.log confirms).

e.g.

```
const onCorrectAnswerHandler = (id, correct) => {
    setRecords(
      records.map((record) => {
        if (record.id === id) {
          return { id: id, correct: true };
        } else {
          return record;
        }
      })
    );
    isComplete(records);
  }
```

Console.log(records) confirms this. Why does it not use the updated `records` since the `isComplete` function runs after the update, and how can I get it to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the function as React sees no change in the object and likewise when you are using an array or object in a state. Try to copy them out by storing them in a new variable.

```
setRecords(
  const newRecords = records.map((record) => {
    if (record.id === id) {
        return { id: id, correct: true };
      } else {
        return record;
      }
    })
   //seting this now triggers an update
   setRecords(newRecords);
);
```

Then as per react documentation it's better to listen to changes with lifecycle methods and not setting state immediately after they are changed because `useState` is asynchronous.

so use `useEffect` to listen to the changes to set is Complete

```
useEffect(() => {
  isComplete(records)
}, [records])
```

I hope this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that `setState` is not actually synchronous. The stateful value is not updated immediately when `setState` is called, but on the next render cycle. This is because `React` does some behind the scenes stuff to optimise re-renders.

There are multiple approaches to get around this, one such approach is this:

If you need to listen to `state` updates to run some logic you can use the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  isComplete(records)
}, [records])
```

---

This hook is pretty straightforward. The first argument is a `function`. This `function` will run each time if one of the variables in the dependency array updates. In this case it will run each time `records` update.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify above function onCorrectAnswerHandler to hold the updated records in temporary variable and use to update state and call isComplete func

```
const onCorrectAnswerHandler = (id, correct) => {
    let _records = records.map((record) => {
        if (record.id === id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                correct: true
            };
        } else {
            return record;
        }
    })
    setRecords(_records);
    isComplete(_records);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please.

```
  const onCorrectAnswerHandler = (id) => {
    records.forEach(r =>{
      if(r.id == id)  r.correct=true; 
    });
     setRecords([...records]);
  }
```